# UITableView grouped with transparency above to reveal content behind it?

Tags: uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, parallax

Is it possible to make a grouped UITableView transparent above and below it's content. I am not looking for a parallax-type solution, but I have a UITableView that I add to my view controller. When pulling down on the table view, I would like to display the view controller view (that the table view us a subview of).

Right now, when I add a UITableView with the same frame as my view controller's view and add it as a subview, when I drag down on the UITableView the header above the first cell is the same colour as my UITableView's background. Instead I would like for it to reveal the content behind it more and more as the user drags down.

Is this possible and how? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it just setting uitableview background to clear color?

Comment: @MortenHolmgaard No, I only want to reveal the contents above and below the UITableView, not in between the cells.

Comment: Okay then I think you need to remove the space the header and footer use with something like this: tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, -20, 0);